# import data from .md or .json file

Tags: json, node.js

I am new and curious to nodejs.

I would like to import data from a json (or .md) file into a node/jade page. Just pointing the direction were I should look would be ok.

Something like

```
{
  "name": "contact_info",
  "workers": {
    "john": {
      "img": "/img/john.jpg",
      "name": "John Mitchel",
      "description": "John is a nice guy...",
    },
    "anna": {
      "img": "/img/anna.jpg",
      "name": "Anna James",
      "description": "Anna is great at tenis",
    },
... //etc
```

and import that so it would render in a html for web.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [require](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules) to load the `JSON` from a file. Assuming you are using [express](http://expressjs.com/) with [jade](http://jade-lang.com/reference/) you can do the following;

```
var express = require('express')
 , path     = require('path')
 , jade     = require('jade')

// load in JSON from a file named data.json
 , data     = require('./data');

var app = express();

app.configure(function() {

  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

  app.engine('.jade', jade.__express);

  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
})

app.get('/', function(req, res){

  // render the Jade template located in views/index.jade file passing in data
  res.render('index', {data: data});

});

 app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Its up to you to render the JSON as you want to in `index.jade`

Comment: That was really nice input! Apreciated!

Comment: No problem at all. Hope it helped.